# Extracting Numbers

Tags: excel, numbers, extract

There are tools to extract a whole number from a cell with letters and numbers.
i am trying to get from a cell with several numbers - the numbers that construct the figure.
In cell there is a figures for example 24783
I would like to extract to 5 different cells 2; 4; 7; 8; 3

Comment: You should be more specific. Which language? Which framework/database? What tools do you mean? What have you tried? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I would like to do it using MS excel

Answer (score 0):

You can access each digit of the cell A1 with this formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1,       10), 0)  // first digit
=ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1 / 10,  10), 0)  // second digit
=ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1 / 100, 10), 0)  // third digit
... and so on
```

But I think there should be better solutions to achieve this.